# How To Make The Nav MenuBar Not Go Across The Whole Page

Tags: html, css, navbar, nav, menubar

I built a nav menu bar, but the background color is going across the whole page, which is not what I want. This is my css:

```
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 19px;
}
#nav {
    background-color: #222;
    }
#nav_wrapper {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
}
#nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    min-width: 200px;
}
#nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    }
#nav ul li:hover {
    background-color: #333;
}
#nav ul li a, visited {
    color: #CCC;
    display: block;
    padding: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#nav ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
#nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #333;
    border: 5px solid #222;
    border-top: 0;
    margin-left: -5px;
}
#nav ul ul li {
    display: block;
}
#nav ul ul li a:hover {
    color: #699;
}
```

Comment: Upload the html code too..

Comment: I think you have to set the width of the nav.  Also, have you played with the width of the nav_wrapper?  Try setting it to something like 500 and see what happens.

Comment: yeah dont know the html  maybe put bg-color in  #nav ul { ... }

Answer (score 1):

```
#nav {
background-color: #222;
}
```

In here you can adjust width and height of your navbar, or else you should post your HTML sample to see your structure

Comment: #nav {
    background-color: #222;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;  
    width: 70.3em                                                                                                                                                                                                                        thanks i added these to it and now it is where i wanted it thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
#nav {
    width: 50%; /*basically how much you want it to span*/
}
```

Comment: #nav {
    background-color: #222;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;  
    width: 70.3em                                                                                                                                                                                                                        thanks i added these to it and now it is where i wanted it thanks for the help